# Share link on Facebook is strangly encoded

Tags: javascript, facebook, url

How do you share a link on Facebook? I have no problem with submitting a top level URL (site.com). When I try to share a deeper link (site.com/anything), Facebook incorrectly encodes the link. I tried pre-encoding my URL with Javascript's `escape()`, but Facebook doesn't like that either.

[image: Facebook Share]

Comment: Do you have any code for what you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deeper links work fine, provided that the link actually resolves to something.  I only get the encoded path if the URL does not resolve at all.

**Update**: I suspect in this instance, resolve = responds with a `200 OK` HTTP response.  The URL you linked (http://veetle.com/v/4d75ad1a6d412) gives me a `301` redirect to http://veetle.com/view.php/4d75ad1a6d412, which in turn gives me a `302` redirect to http://veetle.com/index.php/channel/view#4d75ad1a6d412.

When I enter the last URL into the Facebook share page, it resolves fine:
http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://veetle.com/index.php/channel/view#4d75ad1a6d412

Comment: This address resolves: http://veetle.com/v/4d75ad1a6d412 , but it causes the error in Facebook.

Comment: It's true that the final evaluated URL does not create the weird encoding, but the hash values are stripped when you actually share the link. Instead of sharing site.com/view#123, I share site.com/view.

Comment: Whatever. I'll just have to use a hashless URL.